# Split HTML 5 date input value into three variables

Tags: jquery, html, date, split

I am trying to give the users the option to use the HTML5 date input to invoke the native date picker via mobile web. Since I do not want to have duplicate calls for the same methods whether the users device does or does not support HTML5, i plan on only showing the type="date" input to those who can use it. I want to take the value from the date input on submit and pass that into three defined values. Basically, when the user hits submit, it would break the date into month, day, and year and add those to the fields that the form processor is expecting to receive.

I have something like this based off a sample I found but it is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit').click(function(){
var dateVal = $('#dateCL').val()
var dateLength = dateVal.length;
var dateSplit = dateVal.split('\/');
var dateMonthLength = dateSplit['\/'].length + 0;
var monthCL = dateVal.slice(monthCLLength);
var dayCL = dateVal.slice(dayCLLength);
var yearCL = dateVal.slice(yearCLLength);
$('#dateCL').val(dateSplit[0]);
$('#month').val(monthCL);
$('#day').val(yearCL);
$('#year').val(monthCL);
return false;
});
});

<form action="mailto:me@me.com">
  <input name="name" id="name" type="text">
  <input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text"/>
  <input name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text"/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<form action="mailto:me@me.com">
  <input name="dateCL" id="dateCL" type="date" min="1909" max="2009">
  <input name="monthCL" id="monthCL" type="hidden"/>
  <input name="dayCL" id="dayCL" type="hidden"/>
  <input name="yearCL" id="yearCL" type="hidden"/>

  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7xK53/5/

Comment: Can you process the date server-side instead?

Comment: trying to avoid that. My Java guy is neck deep in changes already and this is for accessibility on the front end.

Comment: Lost my fiddle when I updated:  http://jsfiddle.net/7xK53/5/'

Comment: Don't attach your code to `$('#submit').click()`, but to `$('form').submit()` (and remove the `return false`)

Comment: nah that did not work. really it does not even have to go to the input fields. All I need it to do is be bound to the variables I already have defined for the date of birth. So on submit if it could just populate the values of those variables by breaking the date into month, day and year that would be awesome.

Comment: And now that I look at it, on submit the value becomes year-month-day. So maybe removing the dash on submit, then apply a split at 4-2-2 and take the value from each split and append to the inputs??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work without jQuery on Chrome when I run it local or on my web server but when I try it on fiddle it fails:

```
function PassTheMic(){
document.getElementById('myField1').value = document.getElementById('myFieldx').value;

}


</script>

<form method="post" action="mailto:me@me.com">
<input type="date" id="myFieldx" value="" name="myFieldx" onBlur="PassTheMic()" min="2012-01-01" max="2013-01-01"/>
<input type="hidden" id="myField1" value="" name="myField1" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```